# JavaScript object property containing dot

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I am trying to order an array of objects with the lodash orderBy function.
When the iteratees contains a dot in the middle, the orderBy does not work any more.

Here is a plunker to explain the problem better.
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ogDvQZn8Fw2WqksR?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1)

```
ar users = [
     { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 },
     { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 },
     { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 },
     { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 }
];

_.orderBy(users, ['user', 'age'], ['asc', 'desc']);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You have code in the question, but it lacks the "dot in the middle" that you are asking about!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a function for the access to exotic key names.

```js
const
    getPDot = o => o.value['p.'].val,
    data = [{ id: 'b', value: { 'p.': { val: 2 } } }, { id: 'a', value: { 'p.': { val: 1 } } }, { id: 'c', value: { 'p.': { val: 3 } } }];


console.log(_.orderBy(data, [getPDot], ['asc']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

A dynamic approach with a closure over `key`.

```js
const
    getValue = key => o => o.value[key].val,
    data = [{ id: 'b', value: { 'p.': { val: 2 } } }, { id: 'a', value: { 'p.': { val: 1 } } }, { id: 'c', value: { 'p.': { val: 3 } } }];


console.log(_.orderBy(data, [getValue('p.')], ['asc']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

ES5

```js
const
    getValue = function (key) {
        return function (o) {
            return o.value[key].val;
        };
    }
    data = [{ id: 'b', value: { 'p.': { val: 2 } } }, { id: 'a', value: { 'p.': { val: 1 } } }, { id: 'c', value: { 'p.': { val: 3 } } }];


console.log(_.orderBy(data, [getValue('p.')], ['asc']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz
could you please help me ti write the es5 version of the getValue function?

Comment: how does the o get passed into. i checked with console.log and it indeed logs the current object

Comment: btw @Mohameddev `var getValue = function(key){
 return function(o){
   return o.value[key].val
  }
}
`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/13583510/cmgchess
thank you so much i appreciate your help